# swift tablecell NSTextAttachment + GIF -> gif image not animate

Tags: swift, uitableview, animated-gif, nstextattachment

im try to add gif image to table cell + text attribute, i worked on nstextattachment to show gif image normally, the gif image showed but it does not animate. did someone explain me the problem?

```
let attachment = NSTextAttachment()
attachment.image = UIImage.gif(name: data.Data)
attachment.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: (font.capHeight - gifSize).rounded() / 2, width: gifSize, height: gifSize)
let replacement = NSAttributedString(attachment: attachment)
attributedString.replaceCharacters(in: aMatch.range, with: replacement)
```

[image]

Comment: Did you make it work with a "simple" `UIImageView`, first? Because gif aren't natively supported. There are way to make them work on iOS, but it's additional work. So it's no wondering that for NSTextAttachment (which will have a `UIImageView`  behind the scene), it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gif image will not work with NSTextAttachment. You can use UIImageView for .gif images.